# The axis-label at outer position is not working

Tags: c3.js

No outer label is working,

```
axis: {
    x: {
        label: 'Month',
        position: 'outer-center',   // ignoring!
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%b/%y',
            rotate: 32
        }
    },
    y: {
      label: '% of Duplicated Records',
      position: 'outer-top',  // ignoring!
      // tick: { format: d=> (parseInt(d*10)/10)+"%" }
    }      
} // \axis
```

The `position: 'outer-*'` are ignored.

---

See https://output.jsbin.com/seriyih/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://c3js.org/samples/axes_label_position.html

`position` is defined as a sub-property of `label` so you just need to rearrange a bit (also need the sub-property `text` for the label if you do it this way):

```
y: {
  label: {
        text: '% of Duplicated Records',
        position: 'outer-top',  // should now work
  }
  // tick: { format: d=> (parseInt(d*10)/10)+"%" }
}
```